# Loop through/Update the result until sum of a column(bigint) is less than a specified number

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table with 5 columns - [ID],[Name], [Comment], [Status] and  [Size].
[Status] column needs to be updated for all the rows but only until the sum of value of [Size] column is less than 100. If the sum exceeds 100, remaining rows will be updated in the next call.

I am able to get the sum of the values in the column with SUM function but having problem while iterating it.

Please help.

===============================

**I will try to provide more details**

*Here is the table data*

```
ID      Name    Status    size   comment

 1     File1    Pass    20  Transmitted
 2     File2    Pass    30  Transmitted
 3     File3    Pass    50  Transmitted
 4     File4    Pass    10  Transmitted
```

I want to run an update query :

```
Update [sample_table]
  set status ='Completed'
  where SUM(size)<100
```

So, it should update the status of File1, File2 and File3. Remaining File4 will be updated in the next iteration.

Is it clear now or more details are required?

Comment: please share your table schema, sample data and expected result

Comment: Table looks like this : 
SELECT [Name] (varchar)
       ,[Comment](varchar)
              ,[Status](varchar)
             ,[bytesize](bigint)
  FROM [sample_table]

Column bytesize is having value integer values. I need to run an update on the status column while the SUM of bytesize column is less than 100.

Comment: FYI today is the final day of extended support for SQL Server 2008; you should really look at upgrade paths. 2008 doesn't support the `ROWS BETWEEN` clause in the `OVER` clause either, meaning that the only way to achieve a "running" total is by use of a triangular join or the [Quirky Update](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-running-total-and-ordinal-rank-problems-rewritten) method.

Comment: @Larnu - I understand. Based on the details i have shared, could you please provide me a sample ?

Comment: No, as you haven't given a sample yourself. See the comment from @Sami. Without more detail we can't give you an answer.

Comment: I believe i have provided all the details and scenario intended.

Comment: @PrayasBhatnagar you have not.   You haven't provided sample data or desired results from the sample data.   Without that, your question is too unclear to answer.

Comment: I've added more details, please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: This smells like homework.

Comment: which column are you using to order the records, @PrayasBhatnagar?

Comment: I will add an auto increment ID column to order the result.

Comment: Edited the question with the ID column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

The only way I around this is to use a CTE with your UPDATE.

You can run the following example in SSMS:

```
-- Sample schema.
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    ID INT, [Name] VARCHAR(50), [Status] VARCHAR(50), [Size] INT, [Comment] VARCHAR(50)
);

-- Sample data.
INSERT INTO @Data ( ID, [Name], [Status], [Size], [Comment] ) VALUES
( 1, 'File1', 'Pass', 20, 'Transmitted' ),
( 2, 'File2', 'Pass', 30, 'Transmitted' ),
( 3, 'File3', 'Pass', 50, 'Transmitted' ),
( 4, 'File4', 'Pass', 10, 'Transmitted' );

-- Update all record's [Comment] to 'Completed' with a SizeTotal <= 100.
WITH running_size AS (
    SELECT ID, SizeTotal = Size FROM @Data WHERE ID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        d.ID, running_size.SizeTotal + d.Size
    FROM running_size
    INNER JOIN @Data d ON d.ID = ( running_size.ID + 1 )
)
UPDATE @Data
SET 
    [Comment] = 'Completed'
FROM @Data d
INNER JOIN running_size rs
    ON d.ID = rs.ID
WHERE
    rs.SizeTotal <= 100;

-- Show me the money.
SELECT * FROM @Data ORDER BY ID;
```

Returns:

```
+----+-------+--------+------+-------------+
| ID | Name  | Status | Size |   Comment   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-------------+
|  1 | File1 | Pass   |   20 | Completed   |
|  2 | File2 | Pass   |   30 | Completed   |
|  3 | File3 | Pass   |   50 | Completed   |
|  4 | File4 | Pass   |   10 | Transmitted |
+----+-------+--------+------+-------------+
```

I assume this is what you're looking to achieve?